# Spring - form with 2 buttons sending to 2 different controllers

Tags: java, spring, forms, spring-mvc, submit

I have Spring 4 MVC form with 2 submit buttons. I want these buttons to point to two different controllers. The problem is that one form should have fixed action parameter set.
This is my form:

```
<form:form method="post" action="pageAction" commandName="id">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="addBasket">
    Add Basket
  </button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="addProduct">
    Add Product
  </button>
</form:form>
```

Is it possible that these button will reach two different controllers? I am going to send only ID, in addBasket it would be basketId, in addProduct it would be productId. These are the controllers:

```
@Controller
public class BasketController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addBasket", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addBasket(@ModelAttribute("id") Integer id) {
        //method - addBasket(id);
    }
}

@Controller
public class ProductController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addProduct", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addProduct(@ModelAttribute("id") Integer id) {
        //method - addProduct(id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using html 5 and compatible browsers, you can use form and formaction attributes of buttons to target according to your needs. See details at [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a solution you want, but an alternative might be to use an `if` statement in `/addItem` checking the value of `name`:

```
@Controller
public class ItemController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addItem", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addItem(@ModelAttribute("id") Integer id, @ModelAttribute("name") String name) {
        if ("basket" == name) {
            basketController.addBasket(id);
        } else {
            productController.addProduct(id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would work, but this is not exactly what I am looking for. Maybe I should just avoid this situation and place these buttons in different forms? It won't be easy in my application but it is also not impossible :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add an onclick event on the submit button, which would call the a javascript function wherein you could decide/change the url as per the requirement.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="addBasket" onClick="javascript:addBasket()">

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="addProduct" onclick="javascript:addProduct()">
```

Add any number of javascript functions like:

```
function addBasket() {
var requestURL = '/addBasket';
var formData = $("#formName").serialize();

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    url: requestURL,
    success: function (data1) {
     //do what is required after success
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        //in case of failure
    }
});
```

}